# R not plotting, says Unknown parameter: method (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have just installed `ggplot2` and was testing out some of its functionality and have come across this error which doesn't allow it to plot because of the `method` argument. I am running R version 3.2.3 on Mac & have the most up to date `ggplot2`; below is my code. Any advice how to fix this?

```
library(ggplot2)
str(diamonds)
qplot(carat, price, data=diamonds, log='xy', 
     geom=c('point','smooth'), method='lm')
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do it with `qplot()` (it may not be possible) but you can do it with the full `ggplot()` command:

```
library(ggplot2) 
ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat,price))+
   scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10() +
   geom_point()+
   geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

Comment: `+ scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()`

Answer (score 1):

qplot now is basically a ggplot decomposed. You can easily extend qplot and add whatever you want inside it. qplot now is more inline with basic plot() in R. As far as your question is concerned, you can add geom_smooth(method="lm") in your qplot as:

```
qplot(carat, price, data=diamonds, log="xy", 
     geom=c('point')) + geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

For details you can look into the code of qplot using `edit(qplot)`. Hope this helps.